# How can chalk write on a blackboard?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, friction, everyday-life

Whats the reason for chalk which is used for writing on black board , leaves out white material of it as its gets written over the board ?

> Some people said its because of wear and tear , but what actually happens i dont get , even if friction is there it will resist the motion of chalk going forward while writing but why will it move away the chalk particles too ? Is something impulsive force acts on the very thin layer of chalk just above the board or something parallel to board ??
> **New thought** : it might be that the chalk particles have less cohesuve forces among themselves ? And therefore more attracted to blackboard surface (adhesive type ) just a guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you looked at the blackboard with a magnifying glass, you would see that it is bumpy.  When you drag the chalk across it, the bumps catch on the chalk particles. There are forces parallel to the board on the chalk. The chalk fractures, leaving bits of chalk on the board.  If the chalk were very strong and wouldn't break due to the stress of this catching, then it wouldn't be able to make a mark, and it wouldn't get any shorter.

Comment: Actually, if the "chalk" were harder than the chalkboard, then it _would_ be able to leave a mark because the _board_ would fracture, and the chalk would scrape away bits of the board, leaving a permanent scar.

Comment: Nice @SolomonSlow